# This simple code should generated a deadlock but it doesn't

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

Similar to the question [I posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829271/better-solution-instead-of-nested-synchronized-blocks-in-java), I have this problem that I just can't understand. The code is pretty simple and should (I think) generate a deadlock. I even reduced the number of accounts to 2, to increase the probability of deadlocks.

The code is really easy to understand but to put some context. I have a bank with accounts and I'm doing lots of transfers between accounts. The transfer method should generate a deadlock. Why isn't that happening?

I can only think that the code is running way too fast, but that seems improbable to happen **all the time**.

Here's the whole code:
http://pastebin.com/HWJpuT38

Comment: Why should your code generate a deadlock?

Comment: The simplest solution is to have a global lock on the Bank object.  As locking is relatively expensive compared with the operation you are protecting, this is likely to be faster.

Comment: Try putting a Thread sleep between your synchronize statements to try and force the issue. "synchronized(fromAccount) { Thread.sleep(100); synchronized(toAccount) {"

Comment: Imagine 2 transfers, from 1 to 2 and 2 to 1. It may happen that the first thread get the lock on 1 and then the second thread get the lock on 2. Then both of them will be waiting for one another to release the lock, it won't happen, deadlock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is on this line:

```
mAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>(Collections.nCopies(slots, new Account()));
```

Basically, there is only one `Account` object, but lots of references to it. Thus you're only ever locking on a single object.

If you create lots of different `Account` objects, you should be able to see the deadlock quite quickly.

Comment: Generally speaking, I can't use `nCopies` if I want to initialize a list with "empty" **objects**? Because that will add the same object to every element in the list instead of creating a new object for each element, correct? I know it's not really part of the same question, but is there a similar way to initialize a list of empty objects in alternative to a `foreach` loop?

Comment: No, nCopies will just copy the reference, it won't copy the object. The best and clearest way is just to use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where you have a 'contested' resource is where you synchronize on `fromaccount` and then on `toaccount` - everything else depends on one lock only.

If you had another method which synchronized on `toaccount` and then on `fromaccount` you might have a chance of causing deadlock, but as the code currently is it should be perfectly well-behaved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add some sort of sleep to your loop in `AccountTransferRunnable` otherwise the Scheduler will run the thread until end before starting the other one.

With a Sleep you will give the Scheduler the chance to switch to the other thread will the first one is still running, which will give your code the chance to run into a deadlock.

Comment: Without a sleep I doubt there will be any real concurrency as the first thread will be on-cpu until it is finished with all of its iterations and then the second thread gets its cpu time. In a real world application you always have some sort of sleep (e.g. external I/O)

Comment: If that would be the case and if I added a `println` (to print the running thread number) to the `for` loop, I should expect lots of prints "thread 1" and only after that thread finished I would start seeing "thread 2". Correct? But that's not the case here, the prints are all mixed. Am I looking at the concurrency in a wrong way?

Comment: I think it depends on the test environment, I already ran into this, forgot a sleep on a single cpu machine (test case) and so no real concurrency. But as I see someone else already found the real problem of your code ;) Btw: println also changes the timing behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
mAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>(Collections.nCopies(slots, new Account()));
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29

You end up with a list of 2 references to the same object.

That object can only be locked by one thread at a time. You can never have a deadlock.

I assume you wanted to initialize mAccounts with 2 different instances of Account class.