# Preserving lock order in nested synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I have an example similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829271/better-solution-instead-of-nested-synchronized-blocks-in-java).

After I ensure preserving the order of obtained locks

```
public class Account {
    private int balance;

    public void withdraw(int value) {
        balance -= value;
    }

    public void deposit(int value) {
        balance += value;
    }
}

public class Bank {
    private List<Account> accounts;
    private int slots;

    public Bank(int slots) {
        accounts = new ArrayList<Account>(Collections.nCopies(slots, new Account()));
        this.slots = slots;
    }

    public void transfer(int fromId, int toId, int value) {
        synchronized(accounts.get(Math.min(fromId, toId))) {
            synchronized(accounts.get(Math.max(fromId, toId))) {
                accounts.get(fromId).withdraw(value);
                accounts.get(toId).deposit(value);
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that if one thread performs transfer from account A to B, and another thread wants to make a transfer from B to A, then it has to wait for the lock (correct me if I'm wrong).

What is the best way to ensure that only one thread can make a transfer from A to B, but another thread can transfer from B to A?

I was thinking about declaring two sets of locks for each Account object:

```
public class Account{
    public Object fromLock = new Object();
    public Object toLock = new Object();
    // ...
}
```

And obtain a one of them depending if the transfer is to or from given account. Is that the right way to go with it?

**EDIT:** The question is: assume the withdraw and deposit methods take some time to finish. How would you allow 2 users (associated with different threads) to make transfers to each other at the same time without waiting?

Comment: Quick comment, your constructor you set `mBalance = 0` it is not necessary in java. You can read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html for more information. Also it is not common to name your variables with ´m´ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java

Comment: That wouldn't make much sense: your account would not be thread-safe anymore if one thread withdraws while a second one deposits. The state mBalance must be guarded by a single lock.

Comment: @JBNizet, why wouldn't it make sense? How else would you let me transfer money to you while you transfer money to me at the same time?

Comment: If you allow that, then one thread will try to decrement mBalance while another thread tries to increment it. These two operations must be mutually exclusive, otherwise you could end up with a wrong mBalance. That's precisely why you need synchronization.

Comment: @Emz, I originally reused the code from the question linked. Fixed it now.

Comment: @JBNizet, I edited the question. If you think this is impossible to do, can you explain your reasoning in a longer answer?

Answer (score 1):

The way you've implemented Account, you would never want multiple transactions to affect a single account at any given time. Specifically, since 'balance' is an int, and 'withdraw' and 'deposit' just mutate the value of 'balance' directly, using non-atomic operations, you would never want invocations of 'withdraw' and 'deposit' to be interleaved.

On the other hand, if you were to represent 'balance' as an AtomicInteger, then calls to 'withdraw' and 'deposit' could be safely interleaved. However, if you used both a 'fromLock' and a 'toLock', then at most one account could transfer money into any given account at the same time. E.g. suppose Accounts B and C both want to transfer money into Account A -- using a 'toLock', these two transfers would have to be serialized.

Stepping back a bit, though, why would it be necessary to prevent concurrent *deposits* into a given account (assuming the account's balance is mutated in a thread-safe manner)? Of course, it is necessary to ensure that any given account can be involved in at most one transaction as the 'from' account at any given time; but I don't see why any such constraint must exist for the 'to' account (again, assuming that 'balance' is operated upon in a thread-safe manner).

So, unless I'm missing something here, I think that representing 'balance' as an AtomicInteger and only grabbing the lock of the 'from' account inside of 'transfer' should satisfy your requirements.

NOTE: before I get downvoted into oblivion, let me say that my comments apply only to the specific way in which bank accounts are represented in your sample code (i.e. in production systems that do these kinds of things, there are good reasons to ensure that paired deposits and withdrawals are executed within transactions).